# Deploying a Grails application as a WAR on tomcat7 on Amazon EC2 Linux

Tags: grails, tomcat7

In order to deploy my WAR, I can't figure out where to put the WAR file between these two directories on the system:

```
/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps
```

or

```
/usr/share/tomcat7/webapps
```

Comment: Depends on how you have your tomcat setup/configured but most likely it's /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps as the /usr/share/tomcat7/webapps is the 'template' for future virtual hosts of tomcat.

Comment: Why not just try them both out and see which one works?

Comment: They will both work, actually. However, using /usr/share/ will also make that a part of any other virtual host configuration you add to tomcat.

Answer (score -1):

On my debian server i use /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps

Otherwise you can use the manager :
http://localhost:8080/Manager